# NHibernate parent-child JOIN with restriction on relationship type

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class Unit (e.g. of a Company) which has many relationships with other Units. **I cannot change the database structure.** The db looks something like:

```
Units:
UnitID
UnitName
...

UnitToUnitRelationships:
FromUnitID
ToUnitID
RelationshipType
```

I need to restrict the RelationshipType when querying. I currently have a Unit class with a ISet ChildUnits and ISet ParentUnits (since under different relationship types you may have different parents). I have no need for the RelationshipType in my domain; I would only ever be concerned with one particular Type. If I were writing my own SQL, I would just make sure all my queries had `RelationshipType='FOO'` either in the `ON` or `WHERE` clause.

I'm using Fluent to do the mapping; my existing child mapping looks like this:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildUnits).AsSet().Cascade.None().
 Table("UnitToUnitRelationships").Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Subselect().
 ParentKeyColumn("ToUnitID").ChildKeyColumn("FromUnitID").BatchSize(1000);
```

I think I may need to create a `UnitToUnitRelationship` class and mess with that, but if there's an easier way, I'd certainly prefer that, especially since as noted, I don't need the property in my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `.Where()` and/or `.ChildWhere()` methods

1. `.Where()` aplyed to reference table
2. `.ChildWhere()` applyed to child table

So, I think that you should use `.Where("RelationshipType='FOO'")` to resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Very useful, did not know about that particular method on the mapping class.